# install mongodb on ubuntu 12.04 with out internet connection

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

i'm trying to install mongodb on my computer which has not internet connection but i dont find the way how to install it with out connection to internet. does any one know if there is a possibility to do that?

Comment: Hmmm :\ No you can't download a file without the internet...Though guessing that you have the internet on the computer you are using you could download the binary from http://www.mongodb.org/downloads and copy it and extract it to a folder and then just type in `./directory_to_mongo/mongod` and watch the magic happen

Comment: Can you scp to the machine?